# SQL Request for joining a table and printing its column twice in the result table

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables (A, B) in my database and I'm trying to join them and print the same column of table B twice in the result table. The problem is that I need to put in compliance with two different columns of table A, so to join these tables also twice. I tried to join them and put in the select expression required column two times, but in this case result table shows the same relation in every column.
Here is the result I want, where the `id` column of table B includes `id_1` and `id_2` from table A and the output names correspond to ids from table A.

`Table A: (integer id_1, integer id_2)`

`Table B: (integer id, varchar name)`

`Result Table: (id_1, name, id_2, name)`

Answer (score 0):

You need `inner join` with `tableB` twice as follows:

```
select a.id_1, b1.name, a.id_2, b2.name
  from tableA a join tableB b1 on a.id_1 = b1.id
  join tableB b2 on a.id_2 = b2.id
```